# Excel VBA. How to check if a sub is called anywhere in a Workbook (eg what buttons)

Tags: vba, excel

How do you check where an Excel VBA Sub is called from? It's easy enough to hit CTRL+F to find where in the code it may be called, but suppose there's an obscure hidden button that calls the Sub. How would you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly install the addin **[mztools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx)**. It has an option **Procedure Callers** which list down all the places from where the procedure is called.

The below image shows all the procedure callers for procedure a.
[image]

Comment: But this does not show which controls are assigned the macro, only show those that are programmatically called? Or is there a way to do show all controls?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use CTRL+F in IDE you won't find the situation when standard form button is set to run that macro `on action`. Moreover, any of shape within your Workbook could have `on action` set to your sub. You would then need to check each of it. 
But if you need to check such situation during compilation you could use something like:

```
Debug.Print Application.Caller
```

If your sub would be started from standard button then you get information `Button 1` or `shape name` if was start from any other shape. **Important!** You would require error handling procedure if you use that check syntax for situation when your sub is called from other sub.

For other check Santosh idea, yours, and finally you could write some code which search all modules to find your sub and list it.